# Bash Script that connects to VPN server via openvpn, runs a program, and then disconnects from openvpn server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, openvpn, unison

The operating system I am using is Ubuntu Server 10. I've been trying to cobble together a way to connect to a vpn server via openvpn using command line, run a unison profile, and then disconnect from the vpn connection - all from a bash script. Ultimately, I wanted to run this via cron job every night.

I've figured out that you can run a OpenVPN connection from the terminal by typing in the following:

```
openvpn --config vpn-config.ovpn --askpass pw.txt
```

This is done because the server isn't accessible via SSH. Afterwards, I need to synchronize files between my machine and a remote server. I planned on accomplishing this via Unison, a unison profile, and a having my SSH keys already uploaded to the server. So, after connecting to the VPN server, I planned on running this:

```
unison sync-files.prf
```

I haven't figured out how to disconnect from a VPN connection automatically. Any ideas?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/167272/openvpn-disconnect-via-command-line-in-linux

Comment: I just kill the openvpn process when I want to disconnect.

Comment: As a side note, when you call Unison on a profile you don't want to include the `.prf` file extension. The command should just be `unison sync-files`.